# Is information about caring for my family TMI in a website bio?

Tags: interviewing, cover-letter, websites, personal-problems

The bio on my website currently has the sentence

> I currently stay home to provide and coordinate care for my son, an awesome and spirited 10yo, as well as keep busy with personal and community projects and maintain my programming chops.

I don't want to sound like I'm fishing for sympathy. But this does directly impact my employment options. It's the kind of thing I would want a prospective employer to know upfront.

I am starting to look for part-time work, and I'm sure people will visit my website.

Is it ok in my bio, or should I make it strictly something I bring up in a cover letter or interview?

Comment: Presumably familial commitments are why you're pursuing part-time work instead of full-time so do you have another reason why you would want an employer to know about this up front? Will caring for your son sometimes impact you at work? Often leaving early/suddenly, working around childcare / medical appointments, ... Do you have reason to believe that your situation is so different from other working parents that you need to bring it up that early in the process? Second question: is this website intended as a professional resume/portfolio or is it personal? Is the link in your resume?

Comment: @Lilienthal -- good questions. It's not just parenting. My son has special needs, and it is likely that I would need flexibility. It's true that all parents juggling work & kids have commitments and need flexibility. My needs might be more than most. The site is my professional site. What do you think?

Comment: @abalter Lost track of this but I largely agree with motosubatsu's answer below. If you're still interested in a more detailed answer or input let me know and I'll write out an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine this is going to come down to personal opinion but I would go with restricting it to cover letter/interview, and I'd also restrict it to purely practical considerations that will have a bearing on your availability and ability to carry out the role you are applying for.

Also I'd strongly suggest avoiding the word "spirited" - you probably type that thinking of "vibrant", "fun", "lively". Potential employers on the other hand may read that as parent code for "high maintenance",  from your comment I see that your son has special needs and as you say that will probably require some additional flexibility for you (absolutely agree that your son has to come first!) but again I would raise that in cover letter or interview as a purely *practical* matter.

Comment: "*I would raise that in cover letter or interview as a purely practical matter.*" In most countries you should only raise the subject after getting an offer, as long as the impact on the work is reasonably limited.